# In Flutter, How to open a folder in native file explorer for the user, so that the user can browse its files/folders

Tags: android, file, flutter, dart, directory

I am building a file locker app in flutter which can lock files as well a folders. When a user unlocks a folder I want my app to show an option to view folder contents but in native file explorer. Is there any way to implement this feature?

(Thanks in advance..)

Comment: Check it out [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)

Comment: its for picking files. I want to open file manager with a specific path to open (all in dart programmatically)

Comment: do you mean to launch the native file explorer ? in that case, can't the user directly access native file explorer instead of via your app?

Comment: @RiturajShakti have you found a solution? I want the user to be able to open one specific folder where app related files are being saved.
the open_file package doesn't support that so far.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this package for the use case you've mentioned: [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file)

Usage:

```
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

//Get the path to the directory
final String dir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;

//Use the path to launch the directory with the native file explorer
await OpenFile.open('$dir\\');
```

(**Note:** Tested on windows OS only)

---

If you wish to test on Android use another directory like `getExternalStorageDirectory`because `getTemporaryDirectory` is not accessible outside of your app sandbox.

Comment: This work. Do you know a way to select a file in the opened folder?

Comment: @Apoleo After running `await OpenFile.open('$dir\\');` the user should be able to select a file. You may store the result of that in a variable to access the selected file like: 
`final file = await OpenFile.open('$dir\\');`

Comment: OpenFile.open() on a directory path opens such folder in the native file explore. It doesn't allow to select and return a file, and that's okay. I was wondering if it is possible to have a file already selected when the window is opened, so I can point the user to a specific file in the folder.

Comment: @Apoleo Ah, I see. Not sure if that's possible.

Comment: I tested this with a real android device in debug mode and it is not working. I am planning to test it again in release mode and see what happens. I have a guess that while debugging the path is different than when in release and thus it may not work. it is just a guess.