# How to launch system File Manager from Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

From my flutter I want to launch the default File Manager. I don't want to select file from it for my app. I just want to launch it (preferably showing the directory that I want it to show) so that the user can pick a file from that directory and do whatever they want with it.

Can anyone please tell me how to do it? I see a lot of code and examples for picking a file  but that's not what I need. Just want to launch whatever is a default file manager.

**Please do not suggest FilePicker. That is not what I am looking for. I do not want to "pick" a file. I know how to pick a file. I just want the default file manager app to be launched. I don't want the control to be returned back to the app irrespective of whether the user selects a file or not.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Flutter, How to open a folder in native file explorer for the user, so that the user can browse its files/folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64982099/in-flutter-how-to-open-a-folder-in-native-file-explorer-for-the-user-so-that-t)

Comment: Yes, open_file package seems like it can do the trick. Unfortunately, I am unable to use it because it is dependent on an obsolete version (1.0.0) of ffi. I am using device_info_plus and that requires  ffi ^2.0.1.

Trying open_filex now! Thanks!

Comment: open_file and its variants are able to open a file but not a folder/directory. I want to launch the File manager app. I don't want to launch the app associated with a file type, which is what open_file does.

Answer (score 0):

This was causing me grief too. Here's my solution.

Using 'external_app_launcher' you are able to launch apps based on their URL scheme, so we have...

```
import 'package:external_app_launcher/external_app_launcher.dart';

okButton = TextButton(
  child: const Text("Open Files"),
  onPressed: () async {
    await LaunchApp.openApp(iosUrlScheme: 'shareddocuments://', openStore: false);
  },
);
```

This will launch the app, I'm still working my solution as I want to open my App's folder so will update as I get more.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) package.

Usage

```
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    
    if (result != null) {
      File file = File(result.files.single.path);
    } else {
      // User canceled the picker
    }
```

Edit: Now I understand what you want. Check https://pub.dev/packages/external_app_launcher

Comment: I have mentioned clearly that I do not want to "pick" a file. I know how to pick a file. I just want the default file manager app to be launched. I don't want the control to be returned back to the app irrespective of whether the user selects a file or not.

Comment: Then just await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(); without expecting a return value. There is no package to launch a file picker without expecting a result, if you want to do this without a return value, browse file_picker source code.

Comment: You are completely missing the point. The issue is not about the return value. It is about returning the control back to my app (which I don't want). 

Please understand that popping the file picker does not allow the user to open a file from the file manager. What I need is that the user should be able to do whatever they want to do with whatever file they select once they are in the file manager. The control must not return back to my app. My app must be remain in the background. Just as if they launched file manager directly from the phone all apps screen.

Comment: Check https://pub.dev/packages/external_app_launcher